# Network Resistance equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, passive-networks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYekcz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am having difficulties in simplifying and finding the equivalent for the circuit shown. Can someone guide me to the appropriate start of how to simplify the problem?

[image]

Comment: Start with 'c' at the top of the page and 'd' at the bottom. There is only one component connected to 'c' so draw that in vertically downwards. Same for 'd' but upwards. Can you do the rest? Edit your question and add in a schematic of your solution using the CircuitLab button. Double-click to edit a component's properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip.

Comment: Please explain at what point your difficulties arise. You do need to show effort if you expect this question to remain open.

Comment: My difficulties were in how to start because of the c and d terminal are being in the middle ( i used to see the problem where are they in either the left or right ). Also, because of this, I didn't which resistors are parallel in or series.

Comment: If the the circuit I draw using the circuit lab is right, I belive the wire a and b will short circuit the whole thing and we only left with the two compoments. Req=16 ohm

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Actually, this is not a homework problem ( I agreed it looks like one) since I already graduated two years ago. This question I faced a very similar one yesterday during my preparation to FE exam. I don't expect you to answer since this will help not me however if you guide me to the correct answer I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: My major difficulty lies on how to redraw the circuit where terminal c and d are in one side. this will help determine which resistors are in parallel or series. Mr. Transistor shows me a good star and I redraw the circuit based on his comment. if it corrects the problem is solved for me and I can take it from there.

Comment: Your interpretation of where the ab short is placed is incorrect. You should also mark up the original diagram with the resistor part references used in your incorrect interpretation as this will help you see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: thank you for your comment Andy aka. I insert a new drawing where I changed the location of ab short wire.

Comment: Have you tried redrawing the circuit a few ways?  Start by looking at the equivalent circuit involving only R2, R3, R4

Comment: @user34755: Now move the a-b short up to the centre of the diagram.

Comment: I am not sure but I assume that the equivelant for the three resistors (R2,R3 and R4) is = R2 + R3//R4,

Comment: Mr.Transistor thank you for your comments, shouldn't the a-b short eliminate the resistance R3, R4, R5, and R6? Can you please help me with this concept.

Comment: No, because there is no way to get from R1 to R2 without going through the other resistors. Next step: turn R3, 4, 5 & 6 vertical. Then a light should go on inside your head!

Comment: Using the layout shown in the top schematic, redraw and "squeeze" nodes 'a' and 'b' together as you do so.

Comment: now I belive the answer of part a should be 24 ohms. and part b if we remove the a-b short the answer should be 28.5 ohms.

Comment: You've got it! Is your question solved? If you like you can move the CircuitLab schematic into an answer and you can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs8Br3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit can be simplified to the shown circuit where R3 and R4 are in parallel and in series with R2. The same thing applies to the above portion ( R1, R5, and R6).

The answer to part a is 24 ohms. 
The answer to part b is 28.5 ohms.

Comment: +1. Now you've got some rep!